# Remove vertical tabs?

Tags: 7, hooks

I bought a module on Envato. I've already contacted the developer, but he does not respond. The module outputs some vertical tabs.

[image]

They are created with this code.

```
/**
 * Implements of hook_builder_content_info()
 */
function builder_builder_content_info() {
  $blocks = _block_rehash();
  $contents = array();
  if (!empty($blocks)) {
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      $contents[$block['delta']] = array(
        'info' => $block['info'],
        'type' => 'block',
        'group' => t('Block'),
        // This is name of group to collect contents in a tab
        'block_module' => $block['module'],
      );
    }
  }

  // node add content
  $contents['node'] = array(
    'info' => t('Adding existing node'),
    'group' => t('Node'),
  );

  //Custom text
  $contents['custom_text'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom text'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
  );

  // Custom heading
  $contents['custom_heading'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom heading'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
    'no_title' => TRUE,
  );
  // Insert image 
  $contents['image'] = array(
    'info' => t('Insert an image'),
    'group' => t('Image'),
  );

  $contents['youtube'] = array(
    'info' => t('Youtube'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );
  $contents['vimeo'] = array(
    'info' => t('Vimeo'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );

  $contents['icon'] = array(
    'info' => t('Icon'),
    'group' => t('Icon'),
  );
  return $contents;
}
```

I can rewrite them in my own function, but I have no idea how to remove them. I thought through `$contents['custom_text']` but I'm not sure. Of course, I can remove the original code, but I do not like it.

It looks like `unset($contents['custom_text'])` is working, but can I run this from another file/function?

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_builder_content_info_alter()
 */
function builder_gc_builder_content_info_alter(&$contents) {
    unset($contents['node']);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are showing is an implementation of `hook_builder_content_info()`. Without seeing the code that calls that hook, I cannot answer about removing the vertical tabs, but I can just give some hints.

If the module also invokes `hook_builder_content_info_alter()`, which is normally done from the majority of the Drupal modules using hooks, you can implement `hook_builder_content_info_alter()` in a module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_builder_content_info_alter()
 */
function builder_gc_builder_content_info_alter(&$contents) {
  unset($contents['node']['group']);
}
```

The alter hook could get other arguments, but the structure to change is always the first.

If the module doesn't invoke any `hook_builder_content_info_alter()` you need to:

- Avoid Drupal invokes `builder_builder_content_info()`
- Implement `hook_builder_content_info()` using the same code used by `builder_builder_content_info()` but without those parts that you don't want

This can be done with the following code.

```
function builder_gc_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'builder_content_info') {
    // Remove the implementation done from that module.
    unset($implementations['builder']);
  }
}

function builder_gc_builder_content_info() {
  $blocks = _block_rehash();
  $contents = array();
  if (!empty($blocks)) {
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      $contents[$block['delta']] = array(
        'info' => $block['info'],
        'type' => 'block',
        'group' => t('Block'),
        // This is name of group to collect contents in a tab
        'block_module' => $block['module'],
      );
    }
  }

  // node add content
  $contents['node'] = array(
    'info' => t('Adding existing node'),
  );

  //Custom text
  $contents['custom_text'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom text'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
  );

  // Custom heading
  $contents['custom_heading'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom heading'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
    'no_title' => TRUE,
  );
  // Insert image 
  $contents['image'] = array(
    'info' => t('Insert an image'),
    'group' => t('Image'),
  );

  $contents['youtube'] = array(
    'info' => t('Youtube'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );
  $contents['vimeo'] = array(
    'info' => t('Vimeo'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );

  $contents['icon'] = array(
    'info' => t('Icon'),
    'group' => t('Icon'),
  );
  return $contents;
}
```

The code I am showing should avoid the information is shown in vertical tabs, but it doesn't avoid the vertical tabs are created. The only way to be sure is to alter the function that invokes `hook_builder_content_info()`. Using `hook_builder_content_info_alter()`, you are sure to alter the value returned from all the `hook_builder_content_info()` implementations, while the other snippet I shown just alters the value returned from a module. If there are two modules passing `'node'` as group, the vertical tab will be created, since I am not altering what returned from the other module.

Also, the code I am showing removes the `'group'` property, which I am guessing sets the vertical tab where the information is shown, similarly to the [#group](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#group) property used by fieldsets.

Alternatively, you can use the following code, which removes completely the information about the part you don't want to see.

```
// Case 1.

/**
 * Implements hook_builder_content_info_alter()
 */
function builder_gc_builder_content_info_alter(&$contents) {
  unset($contents['node']);
}
```

```
// Case 2. 

function builder_gc_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'builder_content_info') {
    // Remove the implementation done from that module.
    unset($implementations['builder']);
  }
}

function builder_gc_builder_content_info() {
  $blocks = _block_rehash();
  $contents = array();
  if (!empty($blocks)) {
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      $contents[$block['delta']] = array(
        'info' => $block['info'],
        'type' => 'block',
        'group' => t('Block'),
        // This is name of group to collect contents in a tab
        'block_module' => $block['module'],
      );
    }
  }

  //Custom text
  $contents['custom_text'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom text'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
  );

  // Custom heading
  $contents['custom_heading'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom heading'),
    'group' => t('Text'),
    'no_title' => TRUE,
  );
  // Insert image 
  $contents['image'] = array(
    'info' => t('Insert an image'),
    'group' => t('Image'),
  );

  $contents['youtube'] = array(
    'info' => t('Youtube'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );
  $contents['vimeo'] = array(
    'info' => t('Vimeo'),
    'group' => t('Video'),
  );

  $contents['icon'] = array(
    'info' => t('Icon'),
    'group' => t('Icon'),
  );
  return $contents;
}
```

If this code doesn't work, you could follow the following steps, in order to change the module behavior:

- Check which function is invoking `hook_builder_content_info()`
- Verify if there is a reference to that function in one of the hooks Drupal uses (e.g. `hook_menu()`); the reference could be either direct or indirect (i.e., the reference is for a function that calls the function invoking `hook_builder_content_info()`)
- If this is the case, using the alter hook Drupal uses (e.g. `hook_menu_alter()`), you can change that reference with a reference to a function you write, which uses the code the original function uses, without the part you don't want.

In this way, you aren't directly altering the values returned from `hook_builder_content_info()`, and you need to copy more of the code used from the module for which you are altering the behavior; this is also means that, for every minimal change in the module you bought, you need to check your code to be sure it doesn't alter the expected behaviour.

Comment: I can't find a `_content_info_alter()` in the module. So I tried the second option, but with no luck. My function: `builder_gc_builder_content_info()` has only two tabs, they are extra added. The others are not removed.

Comment: @honline the alter function does not have to exist in the module (in most cases a module does not alter it's own definitions as that would be a waste of processing). The alter functions are called from `drupal_alter`, so in the code you might find something like `drupal_alter('content_info', &$contents);`. Give the first option a try, it might just work.

Comment: @Neograph734, still not working. I tried:
`function builder_gc_content_info_alter(&$contents) {unset($contents['node']);}`

And:
`function builder_gc_builder_content_info_alter(&$contents) {unset($contents['node']);}`

Maybe I do something wrong? (builder_gc is my own module.)

Comment: Please have a look at the pattern kiamlaluno posted. It should be in the form of `mymodule_builder_content_info_alter`. you are free to choose the first part, but it must end in `_builder_content_info_alter` for the pattern to match and the function to be called. UPDATE, just noticed that was your second function. You also must clear the cache for the function to be detected.

Comment: It doesn't work. I used this function again: `builder_gc_builder_content_info_alter(&$contents)` and I cleared the cache. But the vertical tab is stil showing up. I edit my first post with the code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: I should see the module code, to answer that. Without seeing what the function invoking the hook does, it's pretty hard to say which code you should use.

Comment: @kiamlaluno oops, I made a mistake.. I removed the _module_ part from the function. It works PERFECT now, thanks for your great explanation!

Comment: @honline I missed an underscore in the function name; that is why it was probably not working. I will update my code to use the module name you are using.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ah thank you! Does this also work for other functions in the builder module? I tried `if($hook == 'builder_column_attributes') {unset($implementations['builder']);}` or do I think too easy now?

Comment: @honline As long as it's a hook implementation, it works. In other words, if the function is invoked with `module_invoke()` or `module_invoke_all()`, it works. Those are the functions used to invoke a hook implementation. They are also used to quickly call a function without to first check the function exists, but I would not count on that. It's better to assume they are used only for hook implementations.